# print a pysimplegui window

Tags: python, pysimplegui, reportgenerator

I'm trying to create reports, but I see no 'report generator' as I am used to in databases (ACCESS mostly).
So I can create and manage a pysimplegui to show the report pages.

If I can get the exact pixel address of the 4 corners of the Window, I can capture and print it to a PDF file and I'm done.

Is this the wrong approach, if not, how do I get the 4 corners of the window so I can save them to a PDF file?

Comment: `window.save_window_screenshot_to_disk(filename)` will save a screenshot of your window.

Comment: Did not work. Instead of the window that I'm using and wish to save, it gave me a different window. I don't seem to have the right to show you my results with a picture, but both as a jpg and as a pdf, the picture looks the right size, but is shifted way down and way to the left.

Comment: Checked the size, it wasn't right either.

Comment: The Demo Programs are probably your best bet then.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and report back on what my problem was (If I can fix it)